# What is the proper way to express a std::byte literal in C++17?

Tags: c++, byte, c++17

The compiler warns against mixing ints and bytes in bitwise operations. The best way I could find to create byte literals was the constructor syntax `byte(1)`, as shown in the for loops of the example code below. Is this the best way? (Besides defining my own literal suffix)

```
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

void drawMonochromeHLine(vector<byte>& screen, int width, int x1, int x2, int y) {
    if (x2 < x1) swap(x1, x2);
    //DCHECK(x1 >= 0);
    //DCHECK((x2 >> 3) < width)
    //DCHECK(y < height)

    int yOffset = y * (width >> 3);
    int si = (x1 >> 3) + yOffset;
    int ei = (x2 >> 3) + yOffset;
    int sbi = (~x1) & 0b111; // x1=6: 00000011. x1=1: 01111111
    int ebi = (~x2) & 0b111; // x=7: 10000000. x2=1: 01111111

    if (si == ei) {
        for (byte mask = byte(1) << ebi; mask >= byte(1) << sbi; mask >>= 1)
            screen[si] |= mask;
    }
    else {
        for (byte mask = byte(1) << sbi; mask > byte(0); mask >>= 1)
            screen[si] |= mask;
        for (int i = si + 1; i < ei; ++i)
            screen[i] = byte(0xff);
        for (byte mask = byte(1) << 7; mask >= byte(1) << ebi; mask >>= 1)
            screen[ei] |= mask;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your own literal suffix?

Comment: Using `std::byte{1}` is what cppreference recommends.

Comment: @Ayxan nothing wrong with it; I was just wanting to know what one would use if choosing to use C++17 as it sits without extending it.

Comment: just like there's no `char` or `short` suffix, there's no suffix for `std::byte`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the closest thing to a literal byte expression is `byte{0}` as Shawn mentioned, such as is shown in the (bottom) examples on the [cppreference std::byte page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte).

There is no [literal suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) such as there is for float or unsigned.